# Using a prompt to set the innerHTML of an element to a website with a clickable anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor, href, innerhtml, prompt

The following does not work, and I don't know why. The innerhtml of the element gets changed, but I can't figure out how to create a clickable link to the answer of the prompt.

HTML:

```
<h5 class="user-output">My favorite website is <span id="favorite-website">...   </span></h5>
  <button class="button-primary" onclick=app.setWebsite()>Set Website</button>
```

JS:

```
app.setWebsite = function setWebsite() {
    var click = prompt("What is your favorite website?");
    document.getElementById("favorite-website").innerHTML = "find out here!";
    document.getElementById("favorite-website").href = click
}
```

Comment: `favorite-website` is an `<a>` element?

Comment: It's a <span> inside of an h5.

Comment: if favorite-website is a span inside the <a>, you need to assign click to the spans parent, the a.

Comment: Brett: 
`href` has no meaning to a `span` element.

Comment: Add your HTML, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Just added the html